# Ionic 5 emulator AVD Internet connection - error?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying use the emulator AVD, and my app to showed this error

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.16.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn’t respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

How can emultaor my app with Firebase ?

Comment: Have you checked that the emulator has google services installed?

Comment: Hi, I'll verify now and return ok

Comment: well my friend, so , whe I've tryed install only google service, don't work then I installed all tools of google and so its works, thanks its resolve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Frank Van, its work! I installed all tools of google and work, thanks!

[image]